# SVG stroke-dasharray drawing errors in Chromium browsers

Tags: svg

Displaying this SVG at `width=100px` is fine, but on Chrome & Edge & Brave `width=110px` distorts the gold slice.
FireFox displays the slices correct.

Anything I can do to fix it in Chromium?

[image]

```html
<style>
  svg {
    background: teal;
  }

</style>
<svg width="100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     viewBox="0 0 110 110" stroke-width="50" >
  <path stroke-dasharray="90 270" stroke-dashoffset="90" pathLength="360" 
  d="M82.5 55a27.5 27.5 0 1 0-55 0a27.5 27.5 0 1 0 55 0" fill="none" value="90" stroke="blue"></path>
  <path stroke-dasharray="45 315" stroke-dashoffset="135" pathLength="360" 
  d="M82.5 55a27.5 27.5 0 1 0-55 0a27.5 27.5 0 1 0 55 0" fill="none" value="45" stroke="gold"></path>
  <path stroke-dasharray="30 330" stroke-dashoffset="165" pathLength="360" 
  d="M82.5 55a27.5 27.5 0 1 0-55 0a27.5 27.5 0 1 0 55 0" fill="none" value="30" stroke="red"></path>
</svg>

<svg width="110px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     viewBox="0 0 110 110" stroke-width="50">
  <path stroke-dasharray="90 270" stroke-dashoffset="90" pathLength="360" 
  d="M82.5 55a27.5 27.5 0 1 0-55 0a27.5 27.5 0 1 0 55 0" fill="none" value="90" stroke="blue"></path>
  <path stroke-dasharray="45 315" stroke-dashoffset="135" pathLength="360" 
  d="M82.5 55a27.5 27.5 0 1 0-55 0a27.5 27.5 0 1 0 55 0" fill="none" value="45" stroke="gold"></path>
  <path stroke-dasharray="30 330" stroke-dashoffset="165" pathLength="360" 
  d="M82.5 55a27.5 27.5 0 1 0-55 0a27.5 27.5 0 1 0 55 0" fill="none" value="30" stroke="red"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Don't use stroke-dasharray, draw the arcs using paths with elliptical arcs. All browsers have problems with what you're doing on different platforms/graphics cards.

Comment: Not an option. Only have done one experiment, but multiplying everything by 10 fixes it (in one experiment) So it looks like too small a viewBox causes rounding issues in the Chromium SVG parser (maybe Safari as well, as both Browser engines are based on WebKit)

Comment: I  would use `stroke-dasharray="43.2 129" stroke-dashoffset="43.2"`  instead without the pathLength attribute. Apparently there are many bugs related to pathLength

Comment: It all relies on ``pathLength``. User adds ``<slice value="45"></slice>`` in a Web Component to draw pie chart percentage slices, so the pathLength always is 360. I haven't seen any issues yet after re-sizing the viewBox from ``"0 0 100 100"`` to ``"0 0 1000 1000"`` ... fingers crossed.